# WSO2 : Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Controll-Allow-Headers in preflight response when using multipart/form-data

Tags: wso2, cors, multipartform-data, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm creating a POST API service to upload files in WSO2EI. Request using multipart/form-data.
I got error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'x' from origin y has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Controll-Allow-Headers in preflight response

I only got the error when hit the service from frontend using vue js.

I already added option method

```
    <resource methods="OPTIONS" uri-template="/*">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="Access-Control-Request-Headers" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="authorization,content-type"/>
            <sequence key="gov:commons/AccessControlAllow.xml"/>
            <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
```

sequence AccessControlAllow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="AccessControlAllow" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="Access-Control-Request-Headers" value="Authorization,Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>
    <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"/>
    <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="*"/>
</sequence>
```

I also added this sequence (AccessControlAllow.xml) before sending response. I got the error only when the request using mulltipart/form-data and hit from vue.js. Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because, You have defined a OPTION resource in your API. If you have defined OPTIONS as a resource method, then EI sends the request to the backend service to collect the information.

Therefore, Check the API definition and remove OPTION call if exist.